# Send rabbitmq response to web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rabbitmq

This is the gist, i'm quite new to rabbitmq. I've added it to a asp.net webform application successfully. Also managed to send a request and got a response back.

```
 public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IReportProcessCompletionNotification> context)
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("Got the notification for load as {0}", context.Message.Status);

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
              // send message back to page here
            });
        }
```

Now this is where i am at the moment, I want to display the response on the page where the call was made without reloading the page. Any help will be appreciate.

Apologies if a similar question has been asked already but honestly i'm yet to find a solution.

Comment: You can try SignalR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: @opewix, do you mean use SignalR instead of RabbitMq?

Comment: No, I mean call SignalR inside your task. SinglaR then will send a message to your UI and you'll be able to handle it with javascript

Comment: @opewix gotcha, i've not used SignalR before but looks like something i can pick up quickly. Thanks